# How to extract data from another website and ip , location , and country code

Tags: javascript, php, location, ip, web-crawler

I know a site which gives our IP , location and country. I don't know how to extract the data and display it in our site.

**Source website:** https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/

It outputs data something like this : {"city":false,"country":{"name":"India","code":"IN"},"location":{"accuracy_radius":200,"latitude":13.0833,"longitude":80.2833,"time_zone":"Asia/Kolkata"},"ip":"27.62.5.1"}

Now I need to get the ip , code, country name in my website.

We can use PHP or JSON, but i need to display the data in site. I know this is a simple question but I'm searching for a long time but still I cant figure out the correct way to scrap and display the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you found your answer please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a php file simply get file contents and echo the wanted fields

```
<p><?php 
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/"));
        echo $json->ip;
    ?></p>
    <p><?php
                echo $json->country->code;
        ?></p>
    <p><?php
                echo $json->country->name;
        ?></p>
```

for a php file without html tags replaced the https with http

```
    <?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/"));
echo '<p>' . $json->ip . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . $json->country->code . '</p>';
echo '<p>' . $json->country->name . '</p>';
```

results in

```
<p>77.246.49.14</p><p>ZW</p><p>Zimbabwe</p>
```

Comment: how to use this code, How to add json file in html and secondly how to mention the data in html tag ?

Comment: I used php script but its not working , Only empty data returns

Comment: Change from https to http that what was causing it not to work (just tested it)

Comment: @azarudeen if you found your answer please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jQuery AJAX call in a javascript file to fetch that data and store it in your json, then render the json onto your page, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/",
  method: "GET",
  success: function(response) {
    $('.some-selector').html(response.ip)
  }
});
```

and your HTML:

```
<div class="some-selector"></div>
```

This adds your IP address into the div, as an example.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your information. Actually i'm a starter i don't understand that. i got a script where they mentioned like this<span class="flag64 flag64-{{../country_code}}"></span>
                                        </h1>

                                        <h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
                                        <p class="desktop-toggle">{{par}}</p>

                                        <p class="user_info">Your IP : {{../ip}}, {{../country_name}}</p>

Comment: I'm not sure what they're doing there without more information, but essentially what I'm doing in my answer is creating an ajax call (which is basically a way of fetching data from an api in javascript) to the website, and since they respond with a json object, i just use the json they provide to add the ip into the html of the page

Comment: Yes, it works but i need to mention that country code in <span class="flag64 flag64-{{../country_code}}"></span> this tag replace {{../country_code}} by country code like us , uk like this . How to mention here ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you make the request to https://geoip.nekudo.com/api/ and returns a variable 'data'
To get the ip, code and country name

```
data.ip
data.country.code
data.country.name
```